# Dump SVN file revisions for a repository

Tags: svn, bash, scripting, batch-file

I need a script to go through my working copy and for each file and folder dump its SVN revision and whether it is modified or not. Anything working out of the box?.. Need both Windows and Mac versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
svn status -v --no-ignore
```

command should do exactly what you ask. (If you want to hide the unmodified files you can drop the -v. See `svn help status` for more options)